# Reject Promise in Resolve as a Service

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

When i reject a promise in resolve ,this error will be shown on console. 
  ***IN CONSOLE:
    EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): null  error_handler.js:56 
    ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
    Error: Uncaught (in promise): null***

```
@Injectable()
export class PaymentScheduleResolve implements Resolve<any> {
    constructor(private rtoService: RtoService,
                private rtoActivationService: RtoActivationService,
                private router:Router,
                private toastr: Toastr) {
    }
    resolve() {
        var self = this;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let rtoInfo = self.rtoActivationService.getRtoInfo();
            if (!rtoInfo) {
                reject("null");// This will produce error on console

            }
            else{
                self.rtoActivationService.getPaymentSchedules(rtoInfo.Id, rtoInfo.Data.RtoRentLength)
                    .then((res: any) => {
                        if (res.Response && res.Response.Code === 200) {
                            resolve(res.Response.Data);

                        }
                        else {
                            reject(null);// This will produce error on console
                        }
                    })
                    .catch((err: any) => {
                        console.log(err);
                        reject(null);// This will produce error on console
                    })
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Angular 2.4.1 and Router 3.4.1 versions

Comment: What do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
resolve(null);
```

instead of

```
reject(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to reject the Resolver. This will redirect you to the default route.

```
reject({message: err , ngNavigationCancelingError: true});
```

Or you can redirect to the error page

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('errorPage');
resolve(false);
```